Derivation of the Classical Lifetime of Hydrogen
In derivations of the classical lifetime of a hydrogen atom, the key assumption seems to be that the orbit is circular, allowing us to write
\begin{equation*}
\frac{mv^{2}}{r} = \frac{q^{2}}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}r^{2}}
\end{equation*}
with $r$ the radius of the orbit. The derivations then go on to calculate the time it would take the electron to collapse into the nucleus if classical physics (and in particular, the above equation) were correct.
I'm having trouble understanding the logic here. How does one justify the assumption that the orbit is circular if the point of the argument is that the orbit is not circular, but actually that the electron spirals into the nucleus? Is the idea that at any given time the orbit is approximately circular, so the calculations are justified?

We know from the fact that reality exists and hydrogen exists and so forth, that matter is stable enough; if classical mechanics is supposed to be applicable to the hydrogen atom, then the hydrogen atom ought to stay stable for at least as long as we have checked it to be. That means that if classical mechanics is applicable to hydrogen atom, then the orbit must be approximately circular. We disprove the assumption that it is applicable, by deriving how fast the collapse would have happened in the classical physics approximation.

So the argument is that we assume the orbit is circular, and then we show that this assumption together with classical mechanics leads to a contradiction, namely that hydrogen is unstable?

You are a bit backwards. When we assumed circular orbits for hydrogen atom, it was already initially in the context of Bohr's model. That is, the "correct" new model is already found, and what is interesting in trying out the classical physics model of the same thing is only to estimate how bad classical physics is at tackling quantum physics. There is no need for the physics to be fully accurate, only to give an estimate of the quickness of the collapse, of the badness.

It isn't a key assumption. You could assume (linear) SHM of the same amplitude and get a similar result.

For precise number one would indeed need to do what you described - take into account that radiation rate depends on the radius of the orbit which is changing in time.
But the logic of the QM fathers was that this way you get an estimate for the lifetime. More importantly, it was setting the $upper$ limit on the atom lifetime (the smaller the orbit the higher is the acceleration, hence higher radiation rate). The most important part of the calculation was not the obtained number for the lifetime $per$ $se$, but the fact that is was significantly less that anything that could be reasonably justified (e.g. the age of the Universe) and hence a proof of the failure of classical physics on atomic scales.
P.S. As an analogy, think of the trial of field-marshal Georgy Zhukov after WW2. When the court said that there was no way Zhukov could have legally acquired all those pieces of art found on his dacha, they could just take his most recent (and highest) salary and multiply it by the time he spent in the military and compare the resulting number with the value of his art collection. If someone would ask afterwards what was the logic of not taking into account that junior personnel receives smaller compensation than a field-marshal, you would agree this would only make it worse for the case of the honorable war hero.

Ah, I see. So what we're calculating is an upper bound on the lifetime of hydrogen according to classical physics, and since the lifetime we calculate is obviously inconsistent with reality, the conclusion is that classical physics is incorrect here. Does the classical Larmor formula give a lower bound on the energy radiated, so that we're assuming less energy loss than actually happens?

I am not sure; but I would perhaps be able to say something intelligent if I new what you refer to as Larmor formula.

It is a non-relativistic formula giving the energy radiated by a charged particle. It seems to be used in most classical derivations of the lifetime of hydrogen. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula

Yes, for the classical estimate you use precisely that. But when I say the estimate based on Larmor formula on a circular orbit gives the lower bound it is not because there are other sources of energy loss but because the acceleration is the lowest in the initial largest trajectory ($|\vec{a}| = v^2/r \approx e^2/(mr^2)$ for a circular orbit).

Some derivations (such as this one: Classical Lifetime of a Bohr Atom ) do not assume circular orbits, but instead they consider nearly circular orbits as suggested towards the end of the original question. This is in contrast to another answer here suggesting the use of exactly circular orbits which, as stated, give only a bound. The derivation in the attached link, however, better models the process of the electron spiralling inwards, and thus gives a good estimate of the time it would take if the electron did indeed spiral inwards.
As a bonus, the attached link, in a latter part, also considers what effect a relativistic correction has on this lifetime.
